# Multiple Views with nested views Angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So first off, I'm working on this for a project at work, but none of us have any idea how to do it, so it might be kind of vague.

Here is the template of how it is going to look: [Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gcyd.png)

So View A & B are going to have 3 states in them that will change the content of the view based on which one is selected

The problem I'm having is that only 1 view ever shows up and it is a test template for now because I don't have those views built but none of the sub views of View A ever show up.
HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div ui-view="viewa" class="col-sm-7">
        <!--Content of ViewA supposed to be here-->
    </div>
    <div ui-view="viewb" class="col-sm-5">
        <!--Content of ViewB supposed to be here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

States:

```
$stateProvider.state("main", {
    url: "/main",
    views: {
        "viewa@": {
            abstract: true,
            template: "<div ui-view></div>"
        },
        "viewb@": {
            templateUrl: "btemps/default.html"
        }
    }
}).state("bobtheView", {
    parent: "viewa",
    //This is default for viewa
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "atemps/bob.html",
    controller: "bobController"
}).state("billtheview", {
    parent: "viewa",
    url: "/bill",
    templateUrl: "atemps/bill.html",
    controller: "billController"
}).state("joetheview", {
    parent: "viewa",
    url: "/joe",
    templateUrl: "atemps/joe.html",
    controller: "joeController"
});
//Supposed to route to viewa showing bobtheview and viewb showing the template
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main/");
```

So when I go to the page and go to the root it redirects to the otherwise but nothing shows up, upon just going to main, only the viewb template shows up.

Any ideas? Any way I can format it better too? Is it better to go with "viewa.bobtheview" over having the parent attribute in the mix?

**UPDATE:** So I found a work around, I loaded each of the bobtheview, joetheview and billtheview in html partials, then I refactored it so the view state of viewa and viewb are controlled within a main template that includes the "ng-include" function to load the different templates, and since all of the data that is stored in those views is given via JSON rest requests, there is no change in the data bindings. The problem I'm facing now, is updating that "ng-include" on button click, I haven't done extensive research on it but I plan on doing so and I'll report back when/if I find something. If you have any ideas on this let me know! :D.

Comment: I could be wrong here but usually you make a STATE abstract, not a view within it. Which means it cannot be instantiated directly. I would guess that is why you are not really seeing anything when you go to main. If it is abstract you can't, you have to go to one of it's children.

Comment: I removed the abstract tag as well as made it redirect directly to a child and still only the viewb panel with template shows up, the viewa shows up with the template inside of it (<div ui-view></div>) but the default child (bobtheview) isn't loaded into it, nor any of the other children when directed to their specific urls, I have tried all manner of different combinations for the urls to the child views but alas, nothing has come of it.

Comment: So I don't know if your design is such that you need to have an abstract view, but I just define the views and controllers in each state (as they change in each one) and it works great. Do that using views: { "viewa": {template....., controller...}, "viewb": {template....., controller...} }

Comment: I thought you'll need a state called viewa in order to use parent: 'viewa'?

Comment: I'll give it a shot with everything being inside the "main" state and just use a bunch of nested views and I'll report back depending on my results, but I have a feeling that the viewb panel won't show anything if I do the same sort of thing with in it, because eventually they (viewa & viewb) will have the same behaviour with independent nested views in each of them that can change with button presses using ng-click

Comment: Nope, didn't work, again all I'm seeing is the viewa's default template and nothing inside of the view. any other suggestions I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a viable answer to the question at hand, after extensive research and asking around, I went with the option of having 1 Controller and configuration state

```
$stateProvider.state("main", {
    url: "/",
    controller: "mainController",
    templateUrl: "temps/primary.html"
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

That went into the configuration settings, then my controller looked a little like this:

```
app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "$state", "$stateParams", "$http", function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $http) {
     $scope.viewatemp = $stateParams.at; //Numeric value to represent template url for viewa
     $scope.viewbtemp = $stateParams.bt; //Numeric value to represent template url for viewb
     //Do some other stuff here
});
```

Then the HTML of "temps/primary.html" looked a little something like this:

```
<div ui-view="viewa" class="col-sm-5" ng-include="viewatemp"></div>
<div ui-view="viewb" class="col-sm-7" ng-include="viewbtemp"></div>
```

I did a little manipulation of the numeric value of viewatemp and viewbtemp to get the actual URL, those are being loaded from a JSON request from my ASP.net WebApi 2 Restful service, but all in all, it is quick, rather simple and still gets the job done and allows for further enlargement of the project.

And that there in solved my problem, cool thing about this, I can have as many as these as I want because they are all separate states with nested "views"

If you do have a better answer, let me know! This is only what I found and what worked for me.