# How have in AngularJS with UI Router, multiple and nested views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been reading about [nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views) and [multiple views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) but I can't find an example using both

In a landing page I have multiple views, one after other. A picture speaks a thousand words:
[image]

To consider:

- Every section/view will have full window height, so on scroll I want to change location to `/view1`, `/view2`, `/view3`, etc.
- - That should be compatible with going to `/view1/b` or `/view3/b` and showing subview (`view1.b` or `view3.b`).
- - Scroll should not make load page again.

I have success doing tasks separately but not all together.

Comment: _I have success doing tasks separately but not all together._ - What doesn't work?

Comment: i don't get what you want to do. did you want to display all the views in the same time or one by one ?
You can use the `ng-include` directives to load different view according to variable in $scope.
`<div  ng-if="displayview1" ng-include="'path/to/view1'"/><div  ng-if="displayview2" ng-include="'path/to/view2'"/><div  ng-if="displayview3" ng-include="'path/to/view3'"/>`

Comment: yes i want to display all views at same time. I wanted to use ui router and no `ng-show` / `ng-if` because I thought I would be better/cleaner.
I will try with `ng-include`

Comment: There is not so magic about state hierarchy. There is an example which does really show we you can achieve with UI-Router http://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310

Answer (score 0):

you can use $statePorivder nested view with

```
       config(function ($stateProvider) {

            $stateProvider
              .state('main', {
                url: '/',
                views: {
                  '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/layout.html',
                    controller: 'LayoutController'
                  },
                  'header@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/header/layout.html',
                    controller: require("./headerController.js")
                  },
                  'left@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/left/layout.html',
                    controller: require("./leftController.js")
                  },
                  'content@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/content/layout.html',
                    controller: require("./conentController.js")
                  },
                  'right@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/right/layout.html',
                    controller: require("./rightController.js")
                  }
                }
              });
          };
```

Comment: yeah, this are multiple views, but how can I go to a subview in one on those views? In post example go to `/view1/b`. I need to know the way to create a nested state for one of the multiple views

Comment: Did you see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032957/multiple-views-with-nested-views-angular